# How to prevent memory leaks when dismissing Kivy ModalView instance?

Tags: python, kivy

In my app, I create instances of ModalView that contain child widgets with callbacks that are bound to widget properties or scheduled with Clock. Here is an example code to demonstrate this. I find that `dismiss()` method of the ModalView instance leaves intact the callback bindings and the Clock scheduled callbacks of its child widgets. I have to take care of unbinding and unscheduling these myself. This can get messy when I bind to callbacks that take args (I then have to use `fbind` and `funbind_uid` methods whilst keeping track of `uid`s). Similarly, Clock scheduled callbacks that take args are tricky to unschedule since they are anonymous then, having been scheduled either using a lambda or a partial.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import datetime


Builder.load_string('''
#: kivy 1.9.2

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'Push the button (pu-push the button)'
        on_press:
            root.showtime()
''')



class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    text=StringProperty() # this can be bound to 'text' property of a child widget for observation
    timenow=ObjectProperty()


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(timenow=self.update_text)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.poll_datetime, .5)


    def poll_datetime(self, dt):
        self.timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "polling datetime"


    def update_text(self, *args):
        self.text=self.timenow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print "updating text"


    def cleanup(self, *args):
        self.unbind(timenow=self.update_text)
        Clock.unschedule(self.poll_datetime)
        print "cleaning up"


class MainWidget(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def showtime(self):

        overlay = ModalView()
        container=MyWidget()
        timelabel=Label()
        container.bind(text=timelabel.setter('text'))
        container.bind(pos=timelabel.setter('pos'))
        container.add_widget(timelabel)
        cancelbutton=Button(text='Cancel', size_hint=(None, None))
        cancelbutton.bind(on_press=container.cleanup)     
        cancelbutton.bind(on_press=overlay.dismiss) 
        container.add_widget(cancelbutton)
        overlay.add_widget(container)  
        overlay.open()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mw=MainWidget()
        return mw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Am I doing this right? Does `ModalView`'s `dismiss()` method leave other objects behind that I am not even aware of? What is a good way to detect such objects being left behind? Is there a way to ensure complete destruction of child widgets of `ModalView` instance upon `dismiss()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it right. When the `ModalView` is `dismissed`, its reference in the parent window is removed, and if no other references to it are held anywhere, it will be garbage collected, and any references that it holds will also be garbage collected. However, the `Clock.schedule_interval()` is holding a reference to the `ModalView`, so it does not get garbage collected. This is the correct behavior, as your call to schedule events means that you want those scheduled events to continue until they are cancelled.

An easier way to cancel the scheduled events is to use:

```
self.sched = Clock.schedule_interval(self.poll_datetime, .5)
```

in the `__init__()` method of `MyWidget`. Then in the `cleanup()` method use:

```
self.sched.cancel()
```

You don't need to unbind the `timenow` binding as that will disappear with the garbage collection that will happen after the `cancel`.

Comment: Thank you, I commented out self.unbind(timenow=self.update_text) line and it appears to work as before. I only did a crude check by running top whilst repeatedly pressing the buttons to create and destroy the widgets. I don't know of a better way to check at present.